# Remove brackets from phone number in run shell script

Tags: macos, shell, osx-elcapitan, automator

I would like to create a custom workflow for the contacts app in mac in a way that I can dial a phone number through a hyperlink.

These are my settings:

**Service receives selected 'phone numbers' in 'contacts.app'**

**Pass input: as arguments**

Script:

```
open "http://example.com/dial.htm?number=${@}"
```

My problem is that some phone numbers are automatically formatted with brackets and the link does not work:
+44(0)123 456 789

How can I modify the script so the telephone number comes clean without brackets?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `(0)` here should be removed, right? The number starts with a `0` when dialing from within the UK and with `+44` anywhere.

Comment: The zero should stay. What I need is the sequence of numbers as you would dial them manually on your phone. +440123456789. Any ideas how to filter and remove the brackets?

Comment: You can remove the brackets pretty easily but a valid UK phone number starts with either `+44` or `0` and the brackets are typically used to show the `0`.

Comment: Thanks Tom, my phone numbers already have the +44. How do I remove the brackets from the ${@} string? That's what I don't know how to do.

Comment: OK but I feel obliged to tell you that the number should either be `+44123456789` or `0123456789`. To be honest I don't know much about the environment that you're using...is this a `sh` script?

Comment: Thanks Tom, I understand. I would remove both bracket and the zero inside then (0). The script is written in automator, mac

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` command replace `()` or `([0-9])` with nothing:

```
#!/bin/sh

#Replace only brackets but keep the number inside the brackets
#URL=`echo http://example.com/dial.htm?number=${@}|sed 's/[()]//g'`

#Replace brackets with any number inside - i.e., (0)
URL=`echo http://example.com/dial.htm?number=${@}|sed 's/([0-9])//g'`

echo "${URL}"
##open ${URL}
```

Test:

```
./test.sh '+123(0)223465'
http://example.com/dial.htm?number=+123223465
```